# Dot at start and end in legend or color axis of highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Would like to ask what is the dot is called at the start and after of legend bar?

[image]

Comment: Those dots don't look like a default Highcharts functionality. Could you reproduce it in some online demo?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I been given the assignment to develop some UI using the charting library, and I am unsure this dot option is available in Highcharts functionality

Comment: Higcharts doesn't offer those dots to render from regular API options. However you should be able to create something like this by using Highcharts.SVGRenderer feature. See guideline: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xrv2g7sq/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian and Highcharts community!